# How to deploy Django project in Apache+mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, anaconda

I have a django project which uses numpy and other library.  I use Anaconda (2.7 32bit) as Python interpreter. I want to deploy the Django project using Apache+mod_wsgi.

First, I install Apache24(VC9, 32bit) + Mod_wsgi. Below are my settings of httpd and wsgi files

In C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf, I add/revise the following

```
    Listen 8980
    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

    WSGIPythonHome "C:/Anaconda"

    WSGIPythonPath "C:/Apache24/htdocs/a;C:/Anaconda/libs;C:/Anaconda/Lib/site-packages"


    <VirtualHost *:8980> 
        ServerName 127.0.0.1

        WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Apache24/htdocs/a/project/wsgi.py
        <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/a/project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
        </Directory>


        Alias /static "C:/Apache24/htdocs/a/static/static_root/"

        <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/a/static/static_root>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

in wsgi.py in Django project:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Apache24/htdocs/a') 
sys.path.append('C:/Apache24/htdocs/a/project') 

import site
site.addsitedir('C:\\Anaconda\\Lib\\site-packages')


import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

# os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "philips_crossover.settings")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]= "project.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My probem is that when I access 127.0.0.1:8980, I get errors.

in C:\Apache24\logs\errors.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Apache24/htdocs/a/project/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django import http
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\http\\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.http.cookie import SimpleCookie, parse_cookie
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\http\\cookie.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import force_str
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\encoding.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.parse import quote, unquote
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\six.py", line 90, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\six.py", line 158, in _resolve
    module = _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\utils\\six.py", line 80, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: Can you import `socket and `_socket` in the regular Python interpreter?`>>> import socket` and
`>>> import _socket` work for me...

Comment: @rofls yes, in regular Python interpreter, it works.